# How to split one column containing several values so each column only contains one value?

Tags: r, csv

starting situation as follows:
I've got a csv files with roughly 3000 rows, but only 1 column. In each of the rows there are several values included.

Now I want to assign only one value per column.

How do I manage to do that?

Comment: If they are characters [you could try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887440/how-do-i-separate-every-character-in-a-string-in-a-vector-into-a-column-using-ti/49887568#49887568). Or coerce them to numeric(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871525/r-splitting-a-numeric-string).

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but why does `read.csv` not work? If it's a proper CSV (i.e. comma-separated) file, rows will be split into columns on every `,`. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49909672/edit) your question to include part of your data as sample data. If unsure review how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please give a small reproducible example of what your data looks like and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

convert the file into txt format and then open the data using MS excel. Don't directly open the file. Open it using Open option in file  menu. When you do this a text wizard will appear. You can then split your data by using delimited such as commas, spaces and form multiple columns. Once you are done with it, you save the file in csv format